# Creating Managed Policy in CDK errors with MalformedPolicy

Tags: aws-cdk

When I try to deploy a seemingly simple CDK stack, it fails with a strange error. I don't get this same behavior when I create a different `iam.ManagedPolicy` in a different file, and that one has a much more complicated policy with several actions, etc. What am I doing wrong?

```python
import aws_cdk.core as core
from aws_cdk import aws_iam as iam
from constructs import Construct
from master_payer import ( env, myenv )

class FromStack(core.Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)
        #myenv['pma'] = an account ID (12 digits)
        #env = 'dev'
        rolename = f"arn:aws:iam:{myenv['pma']}:role/CrossAccount{env.capitalize()}MpaAdminRole"
        mpname = f"{env.capitalize()}MpaAdminPolicy"
        pol = iam.ManagedPolicy(self, mpname, managed_policy_name = mpname, 
            document = iam.PolicyDocument(statements= [
            iam.PolicyStatement(actions=["sts:AssumeRole"], effect=iam.Effect.ALLOW, resources=[rolename])
        ]))
        grp = iam.Group(self, f"{env.capitalize()}MpaAdminGroup", managed_policies=[pol])
```

---

The `cdk deploy` output:

```
FromStack: deploying...
FromStack: creating CloudFormation changeset...
2:19:52 AM | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy | DevMpaAdminPolicyREDACTED
The policy failed legacy parsing (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicyDocument; Request ID: REDACTED-GUID; Proxy: null)

        new ManagedPolicy (/tmp/jsii-kernel-EfRyKw/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-iam/lib/managed-policy.js:39:26)
        \_ /tmp/tmpxl5zxf8k/lib/program.js:8432:58
        \_ Kernel._wrapSandboxCode (/tmp/tmpxl5zxf8k/lib/program.js:8860:24)
        \_ Kernel._create (/tmp/tmpxl5zxf8k/lib/program.js:8432:34)
        \_ Kernel.create (/tmp/tmpxl5zxf8k/lib/program.js:8173:29)
        \_ KernelHost.processRequest (/tmp/tmpxl5zxf8k/lib/program.js:9757:36)
        \_ KernelHost.run (/tmp/tmpxl5zxf8k/lib/program.js:9720:22)
        \_ Immediate._onImmediate (/tmp/tmpxl5zxf8k/lib/program.js:9721:46)
        \_ processImmediate (node:internal/timers:464:21)


 ❌  FromStack failed: Error: The stack named FromStack failed creation, it may need to be manually deleted from the AWS console: ROLLBACK_COMPLETE
    at Object.waitForStackDeploy (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/api/util/cloudformation.ts:307:11)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at prepareAndExecuteChangeSet (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/api/deploy-stack.ts:351:26)
    at CdkToolkit.deploy (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/cdk-toolkit.ts:194:24)
    at initCommandLine (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/bin/cdk.ts:267:9)
The stack named FromStack failed creation, it may need to be manually deleted from the AWS console: ROLLBACK_COMPLETE
```

---

And the `cdk synth` output, which `cfn-lint` is happy with (no warnings, errors, or informational violations):

```json
{
  "Resources": {
    "DevMpaAdminPolicyREDACTED": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy",
      "Properties": {
        "PolicyDocument": {
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Resource": "arn:aws:iam:REDACTED-ACCOUNT-ID:role/CrossAccountDevMpaAdminRole"
            }
          ],
          "Version": "2012-10-17"
        },
        "Description": "",
        "ManagedPolicyName": "DevMpaAdminPolicy",
        "Path": "/"
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "FromStack/DevMpaAdminPolicy/Resource"
      }
    },
    "DevMpaAdminGroupREDACTED": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Group",
      "Properties": {
        "ManagedPolicyArns": [
          {
            "Ref": "DevMpaAdminPolicyREDACTED"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "FromStack/DevMpaAdminGroup/Resource"
      }
    },
    "CDKMetadata": {
      "Type": "AWS::CDK::Metadata",
      "Properties": {
        "Analytics": "v2:deflate64:REDACTED-B64"
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "aws:cdk:path": "FromStack/CDKMetadata/Default"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

### Environment Specs

```
$ cdk --version
2.2.0 (build 4f5c27c)

$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux releease 8.5 (Ootpa)

$ python --version
Python 3.6.8

$ node --version
v16.8.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The role ARN `rolename` was incorrect; I was missing a colon after `iam`. So it's `iam::` not `iam:`. I think I copied the single colon from a (wrong) example somewhere on the Internet. Gah...